# Skyrim mannequin duplication fix not working?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have the mannequin duplication glitch on 4 of my mannequins at my manor and have been trying to fix it for days. I’ve been trying to follow these steps I found other people use but it doesn’t work for me? Every time I leave my house the loading screen is only black with fog. I’m not sure how to get a loading screen that has pictures and I am desperate.

> 1) Put 2 of each item that you have been duping into the mannequin's inventory, nothing else. Also, make sure you don't have any more than 4 of each in your own inventory.
>
> 2) Leave and re-enter, making sure that when you leave the house, the loading screen shows an image instead of just a black, smoky screen. This ensures that the house (im)properly reloads.
>
> 3) Activate the mannequin, and remove one of each item from it's inventory. Without exiting the menu, go to your items and put each one back. WARNING: If you have 6 or more items in your own inventory at this time, it will ask you how many you want to place, and this will cause failure. This is why you can't have more than 4 to begin with.
>
> 4) Leave and re-enter, again, making sure that the loading screen shows an image when you leave. NOTE: This is why I like the Riften house, as it's easy to remember which door you went through last, and you can just use the other one.
>
> 5) Activate the mannequin, and remove all the items from it's inventory, leaving it naked.
>
> 6) Leave and re-enter one last time. Again, be sure it reloads the right way. When you go to your mannequin it should still be naked, and will have stopped duping items.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion but unfortunately it still does not work. I have Nordic armor duplicating and I used shrouded armor to try and fix it but the Nordic armor keeps coming back. Although my Nordic helmet is not duplicating anymore eveything else still is.

Comment: Have you tried the alternative console commands, the mod, and the unofficial patch?

Comment: No I have not. But I’ve tried the method you suggested again but instead fast traveled to Whiterun and back to save the game each time and have been having good luck with that. My Nordic armor is gone finally! Thank you so much. I’ve been searching for an answer for so long and this worked.